# Randomizing a function each time its called

Tags: python, random, python-3.x

How can I get Python 3 to pick a random item from a list every time I call it?
I've got two functions that I need to do this with. I've tried item = random.randint() and item = random.choice(), but those only randomize it once then store it into item.

Here are the two functions.
With function 1, I need the item to randomize every time I call it, so the player will get a random item each time. For function 2, I need the the player and rats attacks to randomize within the numbers I've chosen. So whenever the player attacks, it's between 10 and 30, and when the rat attacks it's between 10 and 15. It has to do this each turn.

Is this possible?

Function 1.

```
def chest(sector):
    item = random.choice(items)
    print("You see a chest, you unlock it and inside is '{0}'".format(item))
    print()
    if item in inventory:
        print("You already have a {0}".format(item))
    item_take = input("Do you wish to take the '{0}'?: ".format(item)).lower()
    if item_take == ("yes"):
        inventory.append(item)
        if item == "Armor":
            player["hp"] = 150
        print("The {0} has been added to your inventory!".format(item))
        sector()
    else:
        print("You don't take the '{0}'!".format(item))
        print()
        sector()
```

Function 2.

```
player = dict(
    name = " ",
    att = random.randint(10, 30),
    hp = 100,)

rat = dict(
    name = "Rat",
    att = random.randint(10, 15),
    hp = 20,)


def attack(player, enemy):
    firstAtt = random.randint(1, 2)#Player = 1, Enemy = 2. Checks to see who goes first.
    if firstAtt == 1:
        while player["hp"] > 0 and enemy["hp"] > 0:
            enemy["hp"] = enemy["hp"] - player["att"]
            print("You have dealt {0} damage to the {1}!".format(player["att"], enemy["name"]))
            if enemy["hp"] <= 0:
                print()
                print("You have killed the {0}".format(enemy["name"]))
                print("You have {0}HP left.".format(player["hp"]))
                break

            player["hp"] = player["hp"] - enemy["att"]
            print("The {0} has dealt {1} damage to you!".format(enemy["name"], enemy["att"]))
            if player["hp"] <= 0:
                print()
                print("The {0} has killed you!".format(enemy["name"]))
                break

    elif firstAtt == 2:
        while player["hp"] > 0 and enemy["hp"] > 0:
            player["hp"] = player["hp"] - enemy["att"]
            print("The {0} has dealt {1} damage to you!".format(enemy["name"], enemy["att"]))
            if player["hp"] <= 0:
                print()
                print("The {0} has killed you!".format(enemy["name"]))
                break

            enemy["hp"] = enemy["hp"] - player["att"]
            print("You have dealt {0} damage to the {1}".format(player["att"], enemy["name"]))
            if enemy["hp"] <= 0:
                print()
                print("You have killed the {0}".format(enemy["name"]))
                print("You have {0}HP left.".format(player["hp"]))
                break
```

Comment: What makes you think `random.choice` is not randomizing every time you call the function?

Comment: I wish I could +1 your username, @NoobMcNoobNoob

Comment: @BrenBarn Oh, it does randomize. I didn't have enough items in the list. Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chest()` is fine.

For `attack()`, turn the `att` element into a function and then call it as appropriate.

```
  att=lambda: random.randint(...),

 ...

      dmg = player['att']()
       ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are trying to do this completely classless (perhaps as classwork or as an exercise in understanding functional programming or dictionaries), this is a situation where python classes clean up your code a lot. There are dozens of knock on benefits to this as well. For instance, in this code, I can readily access the min and max attack values, perhaps to display on the character's token on the board or in attack dialog boxes. This is a barebones example, you'd need to expand it and modify it further to suit your needs. Personally, I'd include a "take_damage" function which would process damage to attacks (that way, I can reduce atk_min or atk_max as a function of damage taken if I want or do other damage-related effects within their own function) and for each variable, I'd have another "current" variable (self.current_atk_min, self.current_atk_max, self.current_hp), etc. That way, I can track the original values independent of the current variables and apply item bonuses, magical bonuses, injury penalties, etc without losing the original values.

```
from random import randint
class Character():
    def __init__(self, name, atk_min, atk_max, hp):
        self.name = name
        self.atk_min = atk_min
        self.atk_max = atk_max
        self.hp = hp

    def attack(self):
        return randint(self.atk_min, self.atk_max)

rat = Character('rat', 10, 15, 20)
player = Character('Player', 15, 30, 100)
```

I know that code is longer, but it's far more discoverable, which Future You will thank Current You for 2 years from now (take it from someone who had close to 2,000 lines of kludgey code written on a problem that I let sit for 2 years without looking at it. I had to throw it all out because I could no longer tell what it was supposed to do well enough to change it intelligently).

Comment: I was going to make a game with what I had learned, then move onto classes. Thanks, I'll try this though!

Comment: Yeah, I understand. That makes sense, especially since classes can be very hard to grasp (at least they were for me). I just wanted to make sure you'd considered this because it's the "standard" way of representing them.